# How can I multiply two floating point numbers in MIPS?

Tags: mips

How can I multiply two floating point numbers in MIPS?

```
.data
    doubleval1: .double 6.7
    doubleval2: .double 2.4
    .text
    .global main 
    main :
     l.d $f1,doubleval1 
    l.d $f2,doubleval2 
    mul.d $f12, $f1, $f2
    li $v0, 3
    syscall
```

I've tried to mult two numbers but Qtspim responds with an error:

> odd fp double register number

Comment: What does _"make error"_ mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: when i run the code on Qtspim give massage error said : odd fp double register number

Comment: after the error massage he print the result 0

Comment: Ok. So the obvious thing to try would be to use even fp register number for all double-precision floating point operations.

Comment: what I can do to solve problem @michael??

Comment: @Michael: I can see an scenario where OP mistakenly understood the error message...

Comment: @lemarhadad: Do what Michael suggested. e.g.: instead of using `$f1` use `$f0`. The error states that you cannot use an odd fp register, where odd as in not even.

Comment: yes as  Michel said .

Comment: the problem was because I use odd register. .. thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

If your using double precision by calling mul.d, you can't use odd FP registers. You can only use even FP registers.